# SQL Profiler in Developer Edition

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server

I have SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition.
My issue is that SQL Profiler is not installed, I've tried to reinstall it several times.  SQL Profiler is not under Tools in SQL Server Management Studio.
And the "Performance Tools" under Microsoft SQL Server 2008 in the start menu is not there.

Here is the version number:
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (RTM) - 10.0.1600.22 (Intel X86) Jul 9 2008 14:43:34 Copyright (c) 1988-2008 Microsoft Corporation Developer Edition on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7600:

Is SQL Server Profiler available with SQL Developer edition?
And possibly, does anyone have a hint how I can get this fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed SQL Profiler is available in SQL Server 2008 Developer Edition.

> The features supported by SQL Server Enterprise, Developer, and Evaluation are the same.

[Features Supported on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx)

Likely you'll have to go back into the SQL 2008 installer and modify the installation options to include the **Management Tools - Complete** features. If this feature is not selectable, you may have installed a lower edition (such as Express). You'll need to perform an edition upgrade on the shared features, then run the installer again. The feature should now be selectable.

[image]